# Windows file path in string getting confused for escape characters

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, escaping

How can I save to a Windows path without Unity thinking the \ is an escape character? I'm getting errors like this: Assets/_Scripts/CaptureSaveScreenshot.cs(50,93): error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence `\k'

```
public void GrabIt(string capturePath)
{   
    string dtString = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");

    if(width > 0 && height > 0)
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsWebPlayer)
            snapShot.CaptureAndSaveAtPath(x, y, width, height, "C:\Users\kenmarold\Screenshots\screenshot_"+dtString+".png");   // Save to Windows

        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXWebPlayer)
            snapShot.CaptureAndSaveAtPath(x, y, width, height, "/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/screenshot_"+dtString+".png");     // Save to Mac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@` symbol before the string like so:

```
 snapShot.CaptureAndSaveAtPath(x, y, width, height, 
             @"C:\Users\kenmarold\Screenshots\screenshot_"+
             dtString + ".png");   // Save to Windows
```

That tells the compiler to treat everything in the string as literal and doesn't require you to escape everything.  This is great when using file paths.

Comment: They call it Verbatim Strings :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\` in path string so it would consider it as `\`.

Like

```
"C:\\Users\\kenmarold\\Screenshots\\screenshot_"+dtString+".png"
```

Learn more about [Escape Sequences in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

OR you can use [Verbatim String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) instead of Escape Sequence.

And Thumb Up if its helpful.

Comment: The OP didn't specify C#, although the code sample *does* look like C#...  ;-)

Comment: @Craig it is C# for sure and its tagged under unity3d. =]

Comment: Forgot to tag it C# sorry about that. Is there anything else I need to do to save a file if my application is running in the WebPlayer? Still getting nothing. Works great in the editor, no go in the WebPlayer.

Comment: I assume it's not possble, just wasn't sure if there was anything I could if I was running the web app locally in a browser versus serving it up remotely. Probably doesn't make a difference. Works fine natively though.

Comment: @KenMarold Look what i have found here:
 http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/save-the-screenshot-to-a-file-from-webplayer.131759/

Comment: @UmairM Unity3d is a cross-platform game engine, first released for OSX--not just a c# thing. ;-)

Comment: Yeah you are right but what i meant is that they only support C#, Js and Boo. And as per my knowledge this code is not Js or Boo. So it must be C# :) and i guess we can write scripts in C# while using Unity in OSX :)

Comment: If the string will not contain any escape sequences another option would be to use the ["verbatim string literal"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) by placing an `@` before the string's opening double-quote.